# Is there a simple way to generate the lowercase and uppercase English alphabet in Rust?

Tags: string, rust

This is what I'm doing so far:

```
fn main() {
    let a = (0..58).map(|c| ((c + 'A' as u8) as char).to_string())
                       .filter(|s| !String::from("[\\]^_`").contains(s) )
                       .collect::<Vec<_>>();    

    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Output is:

```
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
```

Also no crates if possible.

Comment: why no crates? Would have suggested the official regex crates with a filter on `\w` to generate all the alphabets in all languages.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. Just hoping for another way using no crates

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot iterate over a range of `char`s directly, so with a little casting we can do this:

```
let alphabet = (b'A'..=b'z')           // Start as u8
        .map(|c| c as char)            // Convert all to chars
        .filter(|c| c.is_alphabetic()) // Filter only alphabetic chars
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();          // Collect as Vec<char>
```

or, combining the `map` and `filter` into `filter_map`

```
let alphabet = (b'A'..=b'z')                               // Start as u8
        .filter_map(|c| {
            let c = c as char;                             // Convert to char
            if c.is_alphabetic() { Some(c) } else { None } // Filter only alphabetic chars
        })          
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `'A' < 'z'`?

Comment: @Boiethios [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)), it's a unicode standard which rustc uses.

Answer (score 15):

There are many options; you can do the following:

```
fn main() {
    let alphabet = String::from_utf8(
        (b'a'..=b'z').chain(b'A'..=b'Z').collect()
    ).unwrap();

    println!("{}", alphabet);
}
```

This way you don't need to remember the ASCII numbers.

Comment: Any possible way to do that as 1 assignment?

Comment: Awesome!! I assume this will work on stable as well?

Comment: @GoldenChrysanthem it will as soon as the [`inclusive_range_syntax` feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28237) is stabilized, though then the syntax will probably be `..=` instead of `...`.

Comment: @GoldenChrysanthem You can get the vector in stable Rust this way: `let alphabet = ('a' as u8..'z' as u8 + 1).chain(('A' as u8..'Z' as u8 + 1)).map(|i| i as char).collect::<Vec<_>>();` I think this is the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an int to a char in given base. Here the code for `'a'` to `'z'`:

```
use std::char;

fn main() {
    let alphabet = (10..36).map(|i| char::from_digit(i, 36).unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    println!("{:?}", alphabet);
}
```

Ouput:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

For the whole solution, you can create another one with uppercase, and concatenate the two.

Example of the whole solution:

```
use std::char;

fn main() {
    let mut lowercase = (10..36).map(|i| char::from_digit(i, 36).unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let mut alphabet = lowercase.iter().map(|c| c.to_uppercase().next().unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    alphabet.append(&mut lowercase);

    println!("{:?}", alphabet);
}
```

That being said, I think it is easier to just write the vector with literals.

Comment: Looks good. I was also thinking of another way where you filter the range eg like (10..36) but you skip over the non letters with a if statement but got stuck on what to do for the else part

Answer (score 1):

Unless you for some reason (say, an assignment) need to actually generate the characters, the simplest, shortest code is of course just a literal:

```
fn main() {
    let alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    println!("{:?}", alpha);
}
```

If you need the chars individually:

```
fn main() {
    let chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".chars();

    // If you for some reason need a Vec:
    println!("{:?}", chars.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for alphabet in 'a'..='z' {
println!("{}", alphabet );
}
```

It prints all the alphabets in lower case.

Comment: This answer adds no extra value to the question asked. Plus, it's incorrect—OP wants both lowercase _and_ uppercase.